# Show toast message on toggle switch change

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, toast

I am working on `cordova` in visual studio. I am created a sample application that will show `json data` on `chart`. Also i have placed a `toggle button` in my app. Now i want to show a `toast message` on changing the toggle from `off` to `on` and `on` to `off`. Right now i am showing an alert message. Bellow is my `html` code for toggle.

```
<div class="question" style="font-size:x-large; text-align:center">
        Toggle On/Off
    </div>
    <div class="switch" style="text-align:-webkit-center">
        <input id="cmn-toggle-7" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-yes-no" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
        <label for="cmn-toggle-7" data-on="On" data-off="Off"></label>
    </div>
```

For `javascript` see the bellow code

```
$("#cmn-toggle-7").on("change", function (event) {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                alert("Switch is On");
            } else {
                alert("Switch is Off");
            }
        });
```

On `$(this).is(":checked") or not checked` i want to show same message on toast for 20 seconds as it's showing on alert

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using `toastr` in `jquery` as it's easy to use. I just need to install it through [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/toastr/) and performed the following steps.

1. Link to `toastr.ss` `<link href="toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
2. Link to `toastr.js` `<script src="toastr.js"></script>`
3. use toastr to display a toast for info, success, warning or error

`// Display an info toast with no title
toastr.info('Are you the 6 fingered man?')`

`//Display a success toast with no title
toastr.success('Switch is on','',{timeOut: 2000})`

For more information refer to the link in [github](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this code;

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Snackbar</button>

<div id="snackbar">Some text some message..</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")
    x.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
}
</script>
```

For more information, here is the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_snackbar.asp)

Answer (score 0):

**Cordova Soluation**

Your alert is working so you do not need to change it just add a plugin of toast [PhoneGap Toast plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin) and set toast into your conditions

```
$("#cmn-toggle-7").on("change", function (event) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        //alert("Switch is On");
        window.plugins.toast.showWithOptions(
        {
            message: "Switch is On",
            duration: "short", // which is 2000 ms. "long" is 4000. Or specify the nr of ms yourself.
            position: "bottom",
            addPixelsY: -40  // added a negative value to move it up a bit (default 0)
        },
            onSuccess, // optional
            onError    // optional
        );
    } else {
        //alert("Switch is Off");
        window.plugins.toast.showWithOptions(
        {
            message: "Switch is Off",
            duration: "short", // which is 2000 ms. "long" is 4000. Or specify the nr of ms yourself.
            position: "bottom",
            addPixelsY: -40  // added a negative value to move it up a bit (default 0)
        },
            onSuccess, // optional
            onError    // optional
        );
    }
});

function onSuccess(){}
function onError(){}
```

Comment: I actually did tried for it, i installed it manually by adding `<feature name="Toast">
  <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.Toast" />
</feature>` and other per-requisites but during code run i got error `node is not recognized as external or internal command`